# echo mysql data only once in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have managed to make a php chat where each message gets a row in my database table, the user_from column will of course be the same multiple times. Now I want to echo the latest message sent to or from the logged in user. I only manage to echo every message by using this code.

```
 <?php

  $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privat_mess WHERE userid_to='$idn' OR      
  userid='$idn' ORDER BY identitet DESC");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
     $id = $row['identitet'];
     $userid = $row['userid'];
     $userid_to = $row['userid_to'];
     $user_from = $row['user_from'];
     $user_to = $row['user_to'];
     $msg_body = $row['msg_body'];
     $opened = $row['opened'];


    if($userid == $idn) {
    echo '<div class>
        <p><strong>'.$user_to.'</strong></p>
            '.$msg_body.'
    </div>';
    }
else{
        echo '<div>
        <p><strong>'.$user_from.'</strong></p>
          '.$msg_body.'

    </div>';
}

}

?>
```

The $userid is the $id from the users table for the user that sent the message,
      $idn is the id for the user that is logged in.

I'm sure it's possible to use unique_array() somehow but I would be really thankful if someone could show me how or if there is a better way. I also tried to use DISTINCT but I couldn't get it to work properly.

I wan't it to be like the messages on facebook where the one top is the latest active chat. If you press it, you will come to that chat

EDIT:

```
     $id = A_I, primary Key, the message id 
     $userid = the id for the user that sent the message 
     $userid_to = the id for the user that got the message 
     $user_from = name for the user who sent the message
     $user_to = name for the user who got the message
     $msg_body = The message text
```

I want to display the latest message from each chat.

By one chat I mean where the $userid and the $user_from are unique. If the same user sent more messages I don't want them to be displayed aswell.

Comment: Use `break;` once you want to exit from the loop

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions your are using are becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Don't write new code using them, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: Just add `LIMIT 1` to your query, this will only get 1 row as a result.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will keep that in mind Gerald. JiFus, I have tried that but then I only get one message in total, I want one message from each chat

Comment: _I want one message from each chat_ what do you means of this? Please show us your table structure

Comment: Sorry if I explain poorly. I want to echo the last message where the user_to is the logged in user and the user_from is unique. Just like on facebook if you go to your messages.

Comment: @user3910137 see my answer below see it helps you or not

Answer (score 0):

From your comment *but I want one message from each user not one message in total*

Try this :

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     privat_mess 
WHERE 
     userid_to='$idn' 
OR      
     userid='$idn' 
GROUP BY 
     userid
ORDER BY 
     identitet DESC
```

Comment: @user3910137 then you need to provide more details then. tell me the table struture and what result you want. Edit your question to add more details

Comment: Look at the EDIT in the bottom of the post, is there any thing else you need to know?

Answer (score -1):

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privat_mess WHERE userid_to='$idn' OR      
                       userid='$idn' ORDER BY identitet DESC limit 0,1");
```

Will only get you 1 record, the first. I'd sugest you read up on limit for a minute or two since it can speed up your query a lot!

EDIT:

Well, if you only want a solution, and not a fancy one (feels like I left my brain when I got home from work) just take out the identitet you want and then requery each of those:

```
SELECT 
      max(identitet), userid_from
FROM 
     privat_mess 
WHERE
     userid_to='$idn' OR userid='$idn'
GROUP BY userid_from
```

You will get the freshest identitet for each chat and can loop over each to get more info about each.

If you want to solve it through sql from the begining I got another way, but it's not pretty(don't use this on big databases!):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM privat_mess 
 WHERE (userid_to='$idn' OR userid='$idn') AND 
 identitet IN (SELECT max(identitet) 
               FROM privat_mess
               WHERE userid_to='$idn' OR userid='$idn' 
               GROUP BY userid_from)
```

Comment: yes, but I want one message from each user not one message in total. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Okey, couldn't see that from your first post!
PS. Why the downvote? I didn't post a wrong answer to the original question :/

Comment: Didn't work, I think I might be able to make it work if I can make a column in the table which gives the chat an ID. But i'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: I have posted solutions, but I know that there are prettier ways. I seem to be too tired to give you those though :/